# Binding jQuery functions on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, binding, onclick

Thanks for taking the time to read this post.

I'm using the Isotope jQuery plugin, it's working wonderfully except I'm unfamiliar with the idea of binding javascript/jQuery actions and that's where I get lost. I want the element selected through the filter function in Isotope to expand when selected and to the right a block of text to fade in, that corresponds to the element.

I'm aware that I don't need to know anything further about the Isotope plugin to do this, as I said I'm still getting to grips with binding standard javascript/jQuery functions, I'm hoping with this post someone can enlighten me with how to accomplish the above.

Thank you, and best,

Grant

Comment: What you need to do is familiarize yourself with the [jQuery Documentation](http://api.jquery.com). For information about events, you'll want to [go to the documentation about Events](http://api.jquery.com/category/events/). All questions you have should be made clearer after reviewing this.

Comment: Yes I was expecting someone to say this and fully appreciate what you're saying, I'm already reading the page and the like. This issue is time sensitive however, I'm building the site for a client and we're ideally meant to be online for this Monday.

Comment: I've spent the last 4 hours trying to work this out for myself and I'm not having much luck, hence posting. I'll keep trying of course, but as I said it's time sensitive, I'm really hoping someone can jump in with an example I can look at and break down.

Comment: The problem is that the scope of the question isn't a good fit for SO's Q&A. There is no definitive answer and any solutions would only lead to speculation and opinion-based answers. My email is in my profile and you can send me a message and I can see what I can do to assist you further.

Comment: Use `$(".selectorClass").on("click", function(){ // her you bind the action })` http://api.jquery.com/on/ (jQuery v1.7+)